# const uint32_t gives the error: hicpp bitwise operations on signed integers

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, clang-tidy

The code below gives me a clang-tidy error:

> [clang-tidy] hicpp bitwise operations on signed integers

```
// File 1: Clang - Tidy not enabled
typedef struct A {
                   struct { uint32_t b; } c;
} A;

// File 2: Clang-Tidy enabled
A *ptr;     
// Some code that assigns values at the address pointed by ptr
...
...
const uint32_t mask = 0xFFFF0000;
uint32_t masked_var = ptr->c.b & mask;
```

When I change the code as shown below, that error is gone:

```
uint32_t masked_var = ptr->c.b & (static_cast<uint32_t>(mask));
```

In this example, isn't `mask` already unsigned?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in clang-tidy's handling of `&`, not in the code itself. There is no reason to type-cast a `const uint32_t` to a `uint32_t` (and if you do, you should be using `const_cast`, not `static_cast`)

Comment: What version of clang-tidy are you using?  I'm not seeing that error with clang-tidy 10.0.0 (using `--checks=*`).